# Early 2000's fantasy comic about a pale character who felt no pain

Tags: story-identification, comics

I've been trying to find a comic I came across in the early 2000's I believe.

The main character had pale white skin and I think his eyes were either black or tattooed. He was a barbarian type of character who could not feel pain, but that made getting hurt more difficult for him since he couldn't tell how badly hurt he was. Or something to that effect.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: I vaguely feel like I remember this, but I’m not sure.

Comment: I'm sure you should have remembered and mentioned this, but he didn't have a set of lobster claws attached to his hips?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Not that I recall.

Answer (score 5):

*[Kade](https://arcanacomics.com/titles/kade-original-sun/)* is the characters name, I enjoyed this comic back around 2010-ish. This post is 5 years old but I had to answer because it was driving me crazy and I just found this.

[image: Front cover of Kade]

> From a blade separating flesh to a warm embrace, Kade is unable to feel. Kade is the enigmatic warrior who embarks on an adventure to remove the Dark Veil and the demon behind the darkness. Kade must uncover the secrets of the Black Sun while struggling with his physical limitations and his concept of being a hero.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by quoting details from your link directly in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given you don't remember lobster claws, and he's more modern, it's probably not [Lobster Random](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/LobsterRandom), but I figure he's worth mentioning.

[image: Lobster Random]

> *Lobster Random* is a comic strip that ran in *2000 AD*,  by Simon Spurrier and Carl Critchlow.
>
> Lobster Random was once just an average grunt. After being wounded in combat (his first gunfight no less), he is "volunteered" into the Lobster squad and given a pair of lobster claws grafted onto his hips. The result of this is he can no longer feel pain nor does he need to sleep. After winning the war, his entire unit barring himself and his Sergeant are wiped out in an explosion at a celebratory party. Lob himself is discharged and becomes a torturer for hire.

Answer (score 1):

[Lobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobo_(DC_Comics))?

> Lobo is a fictional character that appears in comic books published by DC Comics. The Lobo character was created by Roger Slifer and Keith Giffen, and first appeared in Omega Men #3 (June 1983). Lobo is an alien born on the utopian planet of Czarnia, and works as an interstellar mercenary and bounty hunter.

[image: Picture of Lobo]

Comment: See my [edit], you should be providing a link to your source and also show what is a quote from the source by using quote markdown i.e. `>` at the start of a paragraph.

Comment: If it wasn't for the "he doesn't realize how bad he's hurt", I'd say it could have been a match. But Lobo is this kind of crazy who _does know_, and most of the time, is not bothered by it, since he knows he'll regrow what he lost. Some other times, it's a bit more personal... see [this panel](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-mM5UF8kWyzM/WxZKgQB0-kI/AAAAAAAAGCo/cstqE1GfgKE9S_YtuEUnj1MqfTQ4HjxhQCHMYCw/s1600/RCO011.jpg) :p